# Rails: OnClick event opens url in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

Each offer of
    @offers 
has id and url.
When the user clicks on one of the divs, the url of the offer whose id matches the id of the div should open:

```
@offers.each do |offer|
  <div id=< %=offer.id %>> ... </div>
<% end %>
```

When the user clicks on one of the divs, I want to send him to the url which corresponds to the id of the offer. How do I do this with jquery or coffeescript?

```
$( ".id_of_offer").click ->
  <<< send user to url of offer >>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want to link a `div` to another page, you should simply warp a `HTML` hyper link around it. It's the easiest method. Since `HTML 5` you are allowed to wrap a block element with a link.

```
<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
  <%= link_to(offer), id: 'offer-links' do %>
    <div id=<%= offer.id %>> ... </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to perform more things in your `JavaScript` and not just linking, I would still wrap the div into a link and prevent the default action in `JavaScript` of the link. An advantage of this is, that the website is still working properly, even the user has deactivated `JavaScript`.

```
$('#offer-links').click ->
  # some other stuff to do..
  true
```

You should also keep in mind, that if you are using `Turbolinks` you should register this event after the `page:load` event or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks. But that (the second case) means, I call the same function on ALL #offer-links. But the idea was to pass information from the controller variable to the javascript file and access it there.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery it would be something like

```
$(".id_of_offer").click(function(){
  window.open($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

for an `<a class="id_of_offer" href="url-of-offer">` - just as example as it wouldn't be necessary to attach an event handler for click events on an anchor-tag that actually has the url as href value.
Question is how you relate the offer id and url - are there any links on the page or is the url stored elsewhere? Just not sure about this part of your question: "the url of the offer whose id matches the id of the div".
You can store the url as data-attribute on the div, e.g. like that:

```
<div id="id_of_offer" data-url="url_of_offer>..</div>
```

Then it works like that:

```
$("#id_of_offer").click(function(){
  window.open($(this).data("url"));
});
```

for opening the url in a new tab. If you want to open the url in the current window, it'd be `location.href = $(this).data("url");`

**Update:** As mentioned in the comment, the ids will get created on the fly. Therefore this could be adjusted by e.g. setting a class="offer" to each div and change the jquery to

```
$(".offer").click(function(){
  window.open($(this).data("url"));
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really necessary to add `window.open($(this).attr("href"));` because it's already the default behaviour of a link to follow the link if you click on it.

Comment: @Robin Sure, you're right, it only depends if you want to open the link in the current window or if you want to open the link in a new tab. With window.open() it'd be a new tab, using location.href = url it'd be the current window.

Comment: Or just use `target="_blank"`, because if the user has disabled JavaScript :-)

Comment: But as far as I understand, I can't user #id_of_offer in my javascript, because the id gets created on the fly and I don't know it beforehand.

Comment: @Randomtheories Thanks for the info, didn't know that the ids get created on the fly. Just adjusted my answer for this.